# Pi 4 video recording/encoding/writing super laggy after few seconds?

Tags: raspbian, camera, pi-4, motion, picamera

I've got the 4GB ver of the Pi 4. Trying to using it with Motion-Project and a NoIR Camera Module V2.
Problem is the moment recording starts, it's fine for about 1-3 seconds, then becomes super laggy.
Both streaming and the actual video produced becomes maybe `5fps`.
I've tried:

- Swapping Raspbian for motionEyeOS to free up resources.
- Target SSD/FlashDrive via 3.0 port for video writing.
- Swap out stock heatsinks for better ones and also fan case.
- And lastly, trying different resolutions and framerates.

I'd like at least `1280x720` at `25fps`, but I am unable to even get that.
At `720p`, it's more like `5fps`.

Am I asking too much of the Pi? Or am I doing something wrong?
The initial few seconds are fine, then instantly bogs down. So that's why I'm thinking something's bottle-necking performance?

Comment: **Hello and welcome to this community.** || Have you tested on the motion's web interface? Test the lower resolution and fps, if it gets an effect, it's the problem with device which can because of SD-Card, network environment, etc. Add the config file to the story, it helps experts to answer the question. || "*Am I asking too much of the Pi? Or am I doing something wrong?*" No, it's ok.

Comment: As I was reading my old documents, there was a situation that I've had a problem like yours. I clean install motion and tested another version, then problem solved. I haven't been finding any reason, though.